# Not rendering dynamic data in grid view htmlOptions in yii

Tags: yii

Hi I am using grid view and defining onmouseover event .following is my code

```
array(
"header" => Yii::t('b.asset', 'Thumb Image'),
'name' => 'thumbImage',
'type'=>'raw',
'filter'=>'',
'htmlOptions'=>array(
'onMouseOver'=>"showtrail(" . "'" . $data->url . "','title',400,500)",
'onMouseOut'=>"hidetrail()",

),
'value' => '($data->mime_type=="image/jpeg" || $data->mime_type=="image/png")?CHtml::image($data->url,"",array("style"=>"width:50px;height:40px;","id"=>"changeEffect")):""',
),
```

My problem is I am not getting $data->url value in onMouseOver 'onMouseOver'=>"showtrail(" . "'" . $data->url . "','title',400,500)",
and i am getting $data->url value in CHtml.
Please help me How i can use.

Comment: this will not work, because `$data` only exists while the grid is rendered.

Comment: i am using grid view ...

if i am using in value instead of html options 
 'value'=>'CHtml::image($data->url,"",array("style"=>"width:50px; height: 40px;","onMouseOver"=>"showtrail($data->url,$data->mime_type,400,500)","onMouseOut"=>"hidetrail()"))',

I am getting value but value is string so want to add '' means its coming 
 

showtrail(http://example.in/1409047709.jpg,image/jpeg,.. but i want to  

showtrail('http://assets.mercedes-benz.co.uk/dev/1409047709.jpg','image/jpeg',..

How could i do this..

Comment: I have solved by jquery.
define a class attr
 'value' => '($data->mime_type=="image/jpeg" || $data->mime_type=="image/png")?CHtml::image($data->url,"",array("style"=>"width:50px;height:40px;","class"=>"showLargeImage")):""',
<script>
    
    $(".showLargeImage").mouseover(function(){        
        var srcVal=$(this).attr("src");       
        showtrail(srcVal,'',400,500);
    });
    
    $(".showLargeImage").mouseout(function(){
        hidetrail();
    }) ;
    
    
    

</script>
This works for me.